# JavaScript grid view with paging support

Tags: javascript

I’m looking for an easy to use cheap/free JavaScript gridview that supports paging.

It doesn’t have to be a vanilla JS, something that leverages jQuery would be fine.

Other than the paging, I don't really need a lot (doesn’t need to be editable, doesn’t need to be able to have a variable number of columns or subgrids or anything like that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/)

- free (MIT license).
- Supports paging.
- jQuery plugin.
- It has a lots of functions, but installation is quite simple thanks to examples on the page. Look at [zero configuration](https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html).

Comment: On first examination, this looks like exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks